# How do i write code for handling an empty(Null) date in Flutter/Dart

Tags: dart, date, null

My code:

```dart
              onPressed: () async {
                DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: date,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2020),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                if (newDate == Null) return;
                setState(() {
                  date = newDate!;
                });
              },
```

expected outcome: I have a field where the current date is displayed. when I click on it, I can select another date.

problem: when I click to choose the new Date it works. But if I click to choose a new date but then instead of choosing a new Date I just click on cancel it freezes the debugging app because it could not handle the null code.

how can I fix it?

Comment: `newDate == Null` should be `newDate == null`.  `null` is the *instance* of the `Null` *type*.  Enabling the [`unrelated_type_equality_checks` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unrelated_type_equality_checks.html) would have caught that mistake.